# Rational points on regular curves over global fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

Let $k$ be a global field and $C$ a smooth projective curve over $k$ which is not isotrivial. Then there is a well-known trichotomy:

- If $g(C) = 0$ and $C(k) \neq \emptyset$, then $C \cong \mathbb{P}^1$. In particular $C(k)$ is infinite.
- If $g(C) = 1$ and $C(k) \neq \emptyset$, then $C(k)$ is a finitely generated abelian group.
- If $g(C) \geq 2$ then $C(k)$ is finite (Mordell conjecture).

However, there exist projective *regular* curves $C$ over $k$ whenever $k$ is imperfect, which need not be smooth.

What happens with $C(k)$ in this case? Is there a similar structure theorem given by geometric invariants, which determine when $C(k)$ can be infinite?

Comment: I guess in the smooth case you mean that $C$ is not isotrivial? Otherwise it is more complicated than what you write.

Comment: also $>2$ should be $\geq2$, but that's not enough characters for an edit it seems

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*If the (geometrically integral, projective) curve $C$ over the global field $k$ is regular but not smooth over $k$, then $C(k)$ is finite*:

First of all $C$ is smooth over $k$ if and only if also the base change $C_{\bar{k}}$ is regular.
This is equivalent to $C$ being conservative, i.e. $g(C)=g(C_{\bar{k}})$, where $g$ is denotes the arithmetic genus of the normalization (or in function field terminology the genus of $k(C)/k$), see e.g. Theorem 2.5.1 in [1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06941).

Finally, it is a consequence of a theorem of Jeong [2] that
for global fields $k$ (in fact for all $k$ finitely generated and of transcendence degree $1$ over a perfect field), $g(C)>g(C_{\bar{k}})$ implies that $C(k)$ is finite, see Proposition 5.7 in [3].

[1](https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06941) B. Poonen, Rational Points on Varieties
[2] S. Jeong. Rational points on algebraic curves that change genus. J. Number Theory 67(2):170–181, 1997
[3]  https://arxiv.org/abs/2102.06941

Comment: In fact (so a reliable source assures me) the regular curve $C$ is conservative (i.e. $g(C)=g(C_{\bar{k}})$ if and only if $C$ is smooth. Thus the answer is simple: If $g(C)>g(C_{\bar{k}})$ then $C(k)$ is finite by Jeong's theorem, otherwise you are back in the smooth case.

Comment: Thanks Arno! What is your definition of $g(C)$ in this setting?

Comment: For regular (geometrically integral, projective) curves over a field $k$ we can think of $g(C)$ in the most naive way, e.g. as the genus of the corresponding function field $k(C)/k$, or as the number that makes the Riemann-Roch theorem correct.

Comment: But maybe the following is an easier summary without involving the genus: If the curve $C$ over a global field $k$ is regular but not smooth, then $C(k)$ is always finite.

Comment: Yes this is great. Do you want to update your answer to a complete answer then I will accept it?

Comment: ok, I edited the answer